# How to slice 4d tensor in tensorflow.js?

Tags: tensorflow.js

I have a tensor of shape [1,28,28,32] as output of a conv2d layer. Now I want to be able to access feature maps separately. The result should be of shape [1,28,28,1] or [28,28].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use: `tf.slice([0,0,0,ftr_map],[1,28,28,1])`

`ftr_map` controls which of the 32 feature maps you want to use.

Here is the documentation for using tensor slice: [LINK](https://js.tensorflow.org/api/latest/#slice)

Comment: Thank you, but it gives me this error '''tfjs:17  Uncaught (in promise) Error: Error in slice4D: begin[0] + size[0] (3) would overflow input.shape[0] (1)'''

Comment: @program1232123 try using the `tf` class directly like `tf.slice(x, 1, 2)` and see if that works.  Right now it seems that your input shape is too small to be covered by this range of 1 to 2

Comment: .slice([0,0,0,ftr_map],[1,28,28,1]) This worked, ftr_map controls which of the 32 feature maps you want to use.

Answer (score 0):

[1,28,28,1] the last 1 referring to 1 of the 32 feature maps.

Comment: yes, I want to access individual feature maps.